# How to Reset Variables in Kotlin Calculator App

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I am just starting out with Kotlin so I decided to make a simple calculator app. The calculator works and all but when trying out new calculation it apparently still works with the previous values even after clearing the screen. So for example 2 + 2 will equal 4. If trying out a new numbers to calculate for example I will simply hit the CLS button and the screen goes blank. However, the problem is if I wanted to calculate something like 2+3 it will not equal to 5 instead it will equal to 9. It is adding to the previous result. So a place holder still holds the value from the previous calculation even after being cleared.

My clear Screen listener uses the the `clear()` to erase the number from the screen but doesnt clear the place holder. This is my code block for it

```
 val ClearButtonListener = View.OnClickListener { v ->
            val b = v as Button
            if (newNumber != null) {
                newNumber.getText().clear()
                result.getText().clear()
            }
        }
```

newNumber and result are EditText widgets and are declared with lateinit. So my question how do I reset those widgets back to null instead of holding on to previous values ?

My whole code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.lang.NumberFormatException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var result: EditText
    private lateinit var newNumber: EditText
    private val displayOperation by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) { findViewById<TextView>(R.id.operation) }

    private var operand1: Double? = null
    private var pendingOperation = "="

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        result = findViewById(R.id.result)
        newNumber = findViewById(R.id.newNumber)
        //Data input buttons
        val button0: Button = findViewById(R.id.button0)
        val button1: Button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
        val button2: Button = findViewById(R.id.button2)
        val button3: Button = findViewById(R.id.button3)
        val button4: Button = findViewById(R.id.button4)
        val button5: Button = findViewById(R.id.button5)
        val button6: Button = findViewById(R.id.button6)
        val button7: Button = findViewById(R.id.button7)
        val button8: Button = findViewById(R.id.button8)
        val button9: Button = findViewById(R.id.button9)
        val buttonDot: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonDecimal)

        val clearButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.clear)

        // operation buttons
        val Buttonequals: Button = findViewById(R.id.equal)
        val ButtonPlus: Button = findViewById(R.id.add)
        val ButtonMinus: Button = findViewById(R.id.Subtract)
        val ButtonMultiply: Button = findViewById(R.id.Multiply)
        val ButtonDivide: Button = findViewById(R.id.Divide)

        val listener = View.OnClickListener { v ->
            val b = v as Button
            newNumber.append(b.text)
        }

        //Clear button
        val ClearButtonListener = View.OnClickListener { v ->
            val b = v as Button
            if (newNumber != null) {
                newNumber.getText().clear()
                result.getText().clear()
            }
        }
        button0.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button1.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button2.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button3.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button4.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button5.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button6.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button7.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button8.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button9.setOnClickListener(listener)
        buttonDot.setOnClickListener(listener)

        clearButton.setOnClickListener(ClearButtonListener)

        val opListener = View.OnClickListener { v ->
            val op = (v as Button).text.toString()
            try {
                val value = newNumber.text.toString().toDouble()
                performOperation(value, op)
            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                newNumber.setText("")
            }

            pendingOperation = op
            displayOperation.text = pendingOperation
        }

        Buttonequals.setOnClickListener(opListener)
        ButtonPlus.setOnClickListener(opListener)
        ButtonMinus.setOnClickListener(opListener)
        ButtonMultiply.setOnClickListener(opListener)
        ButtonDivide.setOnClickListener(opListener)
    }
    private fun performOperation(value: Double, operation: String) {
        if (operand1 == null) {
            operand1 = value
        } else {


            if (pendingOperation == "=") {
                pendingOperation = operation
            }

            when (pendingOperation) {
                "=" -> operand1 = value
                "+" -> operand1 = operand1!! + value
                "-" -> operand1 = operand1!! - value
                "*" -> operand1 = operand1!! * value
                "/" -> if (value == 0.0) {
                    operand1 = Double.NaN
                } else {
                    operand1 = operand1!! / value
                }
            }
        }
        result.setText(operand1.toString())
        newNumber.setText("")
    }
}
```

Comment: you are still writing java, now just with kotlin. you don't have to do findViewById with [synthetics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)

Comment: Thanks! but like I said im new to Kotlin so im just hearing of synthetics as of an hour ago

Comment: no problem, my comment is entirely unrelated to your question

Comment: "how do I reset those widgets back to null instead of holding on to previous values ?" - are you sure that this is the cause for the undesired behavior? Wat happens if you also reset *operand1* and *pendingOperation*?

Answer (score 0):

You never reset `operand1`. So the second line of `performOperation` is not reached after you have your first result. `operand1` then still holds the last value you have set in your `when`-clause for `=`.
After `result.setText(operand1.toString())`, call

```
if (pendingOperation == "=") {
    operand1 = null
}
```

That should fix it.